# Upgrade Bootstap 4 to Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, migration, bootstrap-5

Is it a good idea to upgrade big project written with bootstrap 4 to 5 version? Or does it require global changes in every file?

I have just updated my project but almost everything stopped to work:

Dropdowns
Accordeons

and so on

So the question is: Is it a common problem and everyone has the same issues? Or did I do something wrong?

And if a lot of files written with bootstrap 4 - should I change almost each of them?

Answer (score -1):

A key update includes Bootstrap no longer depends on jQuery but will rely on vanilla JavaScript moving forward, with dropped support for Internet Explorer 10 and 11. Bootstrap is also sporting a brand new logo to give the old B in a rounded square a small upgrade.

Before you take a step and migrate from Bootstrap 4 to Bootstrap 5, please remember that Bootstrap 5 is in alpha version at the time of this writing so some changes from the code and updates are anticipated until the release of the first beta version. It’s recommended to always check the open issues and pull requests on their official GitHub repository for open questions and feedback.